Making a new column based on two existing columns
The dummy dataframe is from some Linguistics data.
Looking to make four new columns based on Column type for 'C1', V1', 'C2', 'V2', 'B', and 'E' from the numeric values in column duration.
     file sentence iSentence wordType FCPhrase V1Vowel sampleQuality phoneme type   duration
1 PS_G.TextGrid    kalla         2        G        F       S             B       B    B 0.18929576
2 PS_G.TextGrid    kalla         2        G        F       S             B       k   C1 0.09941696
3 PS_G.TextGrid    kalla         2        G        F       S             B       ə   V1 0.05025876
4 PS_G.TextGrid    kalla         2        G        F       S             B      ll   C2 0.12619718
5 PS_G.TextGrid    kalla         2        G        F       S             B      a:   V2 0.13646904
6 PS_G.TextGrid    kalla         2        G        F       S             B       E    E 0.53416178

Any help shall be appreciated. If it is a duplicate question, kindly provide the link. Thanks.

When posting a data frame, kindly put it in a reproducible manner.

It´s always a good idea to create an unique id per row. Address phoneme if its values vary along with duration. Also, spread work just fine, but it's superseded. You can use pivot_wider.
library(tidyverse)

# Toy data `aux` at the end
new_aux <- aux %>% 
  
  pivot_wider(
  id_cols     = file:sampleQuality,
  names_from  = type, 
  values_from = c(phoneme, duration), 
  names_sep   = "_",
  names_vary  = "slowest") %>% 
  
  rowid_to_column("unique_id")

Output:
> glimpse(new_aux)
Rows: 1
Columns: 20
$ unique_id     <int> 1
$ file          <chr> "PS_G.TextGrid"
$ sentence      <chr> "kalla"
$ iSentence     <dbl> 2
$ wordType      <chr> "G"
$ FCPhrase      <lgl> FALSE
$ V1Vowel       <chr> "S"
$ sampleQuality <chr> "B"
$ phoneme_B     <chr> "B"
$ duration_B    <dbl> 0.1892958
$ phoneme_C1    <chr> "k"
$ duration_C1   <dbl> 0.09941696
$ phoneme_V1    <chr> "ə"
$ duration_V1   <dbl> 0.05025876
$ phoneme_C2    <chr> "ll"
$ duration_C2   <dbl> 0.1261972
$ phoneme_V2    <chr> "a:"
$ duration_V2   <dbl> 0.136469
$ phoneme_E     <chr> "E"
$ duration_E    <dbl> 0.5341618


Toy data:
aux <- tibble::tribble(
  ~file, ~sentence, ~iSentence, ~wordType, ~FCPhrase, ~V1Vowel, ~sampleQuality, ~phoneme, ~type,  ~duration,
  "PS_G.TextGrid",   "kalla",          2,       "G",     FALSE,      "S",            "B",      "B",   "B", 0.18929576,
  "PS_G.TextGrid",   "kalla",          2,       "G",     FALSE,      "S",            "B",      "k",  "C1", 0.09941696,
  "PS_G.TextGrid",   "kalla",          2,       "G",     FALSE,      "S",            "B",      "ə",  "V1", 0.05025876,
  "PS_G.TextGrid",   "kalla",          2,       "G",     FALSE,      "S",            "B",     "ll",  "C2", 0.12619718,
  "PS_G.TextGrid",   "kalla",          2,       "G",     FALSE,      "S",            "B",     "a:",  "V2", 0.13646904,
  "PS_G.TextGrid",   "kalla",          2,       "G",     FALSE,      "S",            "B",      "E",   "E", 0.53416178
)

Created on 2024-05-09 with reprex v2.1.0

Your output is better as I want to keep the Column 'phoneme'. However, it says, 'could not find function "rowid_to_column"'. Am I doing anything wrong here? It's a data.frame, btw.

Hey @Pranav_b rowwid_to_column is from tibble pkg, which is included in tidyverse. Reference here

Hi @Adriano, I could finally sort it out. Uninstalled and reinstalled 'rlang' package but no! Turned out, there was another R session running the same package. Thanks!

You can use the spread function to create the columns you want. Assuming you define the dataframe as data,
data <- data %>%
  select(-phoneme) %>%
  spread(key = type, value = duration)

Here I took out the phoneme column as it has different values for each row. If you want to keep it, omit select(-phoneme), in which case you will get NAs in the rows.

Exactly what I wanted. Thank you for your help. Also, didn't realise, spread () function lives in tidyr and not tidyverse now. I have noted your suggestion about putting the data in a reproducible way.

@Pranav_b tidyverse is a collection of packages, tidyr being one of them. When you run library(tidyverse), you're loading dplyr, forcats, ggplot2, lubridate, purrr, readr, stringr, tibble and.. tidyr!
